# import javascript files in ipython notebook to create a custom widget

Tags: javascript, python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm newer in "ipython notebook" and I would to create a custom widget with ipywidgets using html and javascript. I'm using a javascript library and I wanna know if there is a way to import it inside ipython notebook.

thank u in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into custom.js file it can be found in the Users\username\.ipython\profile_default\static\custom (or jupyter depending on installed versions). Here you can add links to your js files and they will run each time you open the notebooks.

Also you can have a look into notebook extensions (like [these](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions) for example )

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution you just need the put the file somewhere in your machine and then use the magic cell HTML like this:

```
%%HTML
<script src="path-to-your-file"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The way to import javascript files for use in a custom widget is to use require.config to load the script into the widget. For example, if you wanted to load fabric.js from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.7.0/fabric.min.js, you would do the following (note that you don't include the ".js" in the path!)

```
%%javascript
require.undef('hello');
require.config({
  //Define 3rd party plugins dependencies
  paths: {
    fabric: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.7.0/fabric.min"
  }
});
define('hello', ["@jupyter-widgets/base", 'fabric'], function(widgets) {...
```